# NSPredicate to match unescaped apostrophes

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I'd like to check an NSString (json) if there are any unescaped apostrophes, but the NSPredicate won't find it, even if the regex is correct.

Here's my code:

```
NSString* regx = @"[^\\\\]'";
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",regx];
if([p evaluateWithObject:json]){
    //gotit
...
```

I know that there are some apostrophes that are not escaped, but NSPredicate just doesn't find it.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Also if I look at the json I see the apostrophes as \u0027.

Comment: `if I look at the json I see the apostrophes as \u0027.` That means the apostrophe has been encoded.

Answer (score 0):

"SELF MATCHES …" tries to match the *entire* string, therefore you have to use the regex

```
NSString* regx = @".*[^\\\\]'.*";
```

Alternatively:

```
NSString* regx = @"[^\\\\]'";
NSRange r = [json rangeOfString:regx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (r.location != NSNotfound) {
   …
}
```

But the question remains why this is necessary. `NSJSONSerialization` should handle
all escaping and quoting correctly.

Comment: The json comes from a server, but contains some apostrophes unfortunately.

Comment: @kennyevo: Perhaps you can show a (short) example demonstrating the problem and what you try to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex which works for me:

```
.*[^\\\\]\\\\u0027.*
```